# Will iOS handle http cache automatically?

Tags: ios, http

Our iOS developer, use a custom cache for HTTP image request.

But as I know that HTTP protocol has it own cache control. But I can't convince the client team, they said the network transfer is too much.

So, does iOS http layer support HTTP cache headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't rely directly on this for images, especially if you want your cache to persist over app launches, etc. You'd have better to use a networking framework which offers both caching options and image additions :

- AFNetworking offers both with a convenient UIImageView additions (setImageURL: on UIImageView, with placeholder support, etc).
- MKNetworkKit